# Linq query with join - help

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I am trying to write a slightly complex LINQ to SQL query.

I have a table called

```
Fruit (FruitID, FieldOne, FieldTwo)
```

and

```
FruitChangeHistory (FruitChangeHIstoryID, FruitID, Date)
```

What I want to do is return the `Fruit` list, to the view. But the View model will contain an extra field, LastChangeDate. So like: `FruitID`, `FieldOne`, `FieldTwo`, `LastChangedDate`

I need to work out how to join on the fruitchangehistory with the fruitid, then sort the dates and return only the latest change date.

This is what I have so far:

```
var list = from p in EntityFramework.Fruits
join h on EntityFramework.FruitChangHistory
on p.FruitID equals h.FruitID
orderby h.LastChangedDate ascending
select new FruitVM
{
FruitID = p.FruitId,
FieldOne = p.FieldOne,
FieldTwo = p.FieldTwo,
LastChangedDate = h.Date
}
```

but not quite working as planned.

Anyone can help?

Comment: Are you getting an error? And did you mean to use `descending` in your query to get the "latest change date"?

Comment: Sorry I should have explained further. No error - I am getting duplicate Fruit records each with the different dates. Yes that is why I used descending. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
var list = from p in EntityFramework.Fruits
        select new FruitVM
        {
            FruitID = p.FruitId,
            FieldOne = p.FieldOne,
            FieldTwo = p.FieldTwo,
            LastChangedDate = (from h in EntityFramework.FruitChangHistory
                                where p.FruitID == h.FruitID
                                orderby h.LastChangedDate ascending
                                select h.LastChangedDate).FirstOrDefault()
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are using Linq to Entities / Entity Framework and not Linq to Sql.

If your `Fruits` entity has a navigation property `FruitChangeHistories` (which it sounds like it should, since`FruitChangeHistory` has a FK to `Fruit`) you can do:

```
var list = from p in EntityFramework.Fruits
select new FruitVM()
{
  FruitID = p.FruitId,
  FieldOne = p.FieldOne,
  FieldTwo = p.FieldTwo,
  LastChangedDate = FruitChangeHistories.OrderByDescending( x => x.Date)
                                        .FirstOrDefault()
}
```